# How I select the complete set of rows for each Sales Order by one common item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to select all my sales order items based on one common item. In the below example, I want to select all my Sales Order rows filtered by item ‘bread’.

Dataset:

```
Order   Items
10001   bread
10001   milk
10001   cheese
10001   apple
10001   milk
10002   cheese
10002   apple
10002   banana
10003   onions
10003   bread
10003   carrot
```

Desired output:

```
10001   bread
10001   milk
10001   cheese
10001   apple
10001   milk
10003   onions
10003   bread
10003   carrot
```

The result should not include the middle order, number 10002, because it has no 'bread' item.

I tried to use the EXISTS function but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested self join:

```
SELECT a.Order, b.Item
FROM SalesOrder a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Order
  From SalesOrder
  WHERE Item = 'bread'
) b
ON a.Order = b.Order
```

The inner query (b) gets all the IDs which include a bread item. The outer query gets all the items for each of the IDs chosen by the inner query. Unless you have multiple rows in the table with the same ID and a bread item (e.g. `1, bread` and a second `1, bread`) `DISTINCT` is not necessary and will lower performance. Based on the limited information given, you shouldn't have such data if your schema are designed correctly (meaning that if your order has two bread items, it has a quantity = 2 column, not two rows with 'bread'; if it is designed to insert two rows to represent quantity 2 of the same item, you really should change the schema).

If you don't want a nested join for some reason, you could do it this way:

```
SELECT a.Order, a.Item
FROM SalesOrder a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  From SalesOrder b
  WHERE b.Item = 'bread'
  AND b.Order = a.Order
)
```

You mentioned you tried to use `EXISTS` but didn't get it working; here's how to do it. In almost all cases `WHERE EXISTS` and the `WHERE IN` version which other answers have suggested will generate the same plan (`DISTINCT` is still not necessary and will make a difference, though). It's possible but rather unlikely that there will be a difference based on statistics, indexes, etc., but you shouldn't worry about this.

Regardless of which query you use, having an index on `Item` will speed it up (whether you should add such an index if you don't have one is a completely separate question). String comparison scans aren't terribly performant on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact datamodel, you'll probably have to end up doing something like a subquery:

```
SELECT 
   SalesOrderLineID
,  SalesOrderLineItem 
FROM dbo.SalesOrderLines 
WHERE SalesOrderLineID IN 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT 
      SalesOrderLineID 
   FROM dbo.SalesOrderLines 
   WHERE SalesOrderLineItem = 'Bread'
)
```

This will be OK for a small dataset, but if it grows to millions of rows, you'll want to review the query and possibly change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select SalesOrderLineID, SalesOrderLineItem FROM dbo.SalesOrderLines where SalesOrderLineID IN 
(
select DISTINCT SalesOrderLineID FROM dbo.SalesOrderLines where SalesOrderLineItem = 'Bread'
)
```